# Searching an order between two dates Hibernate, Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have an Entity as Orders in which i have a column as Date. Now i want to do a custom search to return all orders between two dates. How can I do that??

Here is the Order Entity

```
    package com.example.API.Entities;


import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
     private Date date;
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        date = new Date();
    }

    @PostPersist
    protected void onUpdate() {
        date = new Date();
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Orders(){}
    public Orders(BigInteger id, Date date,BigInteger userId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.user=new User(userId," ",0000000000L," ");
    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Here is the Repository

```
    public interface OrdersRepository extends CrudRepository<Orders,BigInteger> {
    public List<Orders>findByUserId(BigInteger userId);
}
```

I am confused as to how to write the method findAllByDate

I want to Hit an API as well to do that.
Anything would be of great help
So should i have a request Body as well or is there any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method like this in your repository

```
 public List<Orders> findByDateBetween(Date from, Date to)
```

spring-data will take care of the rest. This will fetch the orders which has date between from and to

Comment: And how do I get 'from' and 'to' from the user?

Comment: It depends on your requirement and architecture. Cannot suggest unless i know full details. You can accept dates from user however you want. But this method will fetch u the results u want, given to dates.

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: How are you savin the orders. Do you ahve a Rest call? if yes, then get the date from user as a rest request. Do upvote/accept the answer

Comment: the between here indicates equal to first and lower than the end, or in case i need the end included, which function can i use please?